# Splitting a web.config connection string

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I just started on PowerShell and I am trying to split a connection string that is saved as a string. I have attempted regex and array splits but since I am learning I am looking for an entry level idea.

Below is a connection string example I am trying to split with each of the key areas being assigned to a variable.

```
@{connectionString=Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=catalog;User ID=userid;Password=password}
```

I would ideally like each of the values made available to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I removed the `@{` and `}` from the string. I'm sure you can do some pre-processing to the string to trim these out.

```
$string = "connectionString=Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=catalog;User ID=userid;Password=password"
$res = $string.Split(";")
$connString = $res[0]
$initialCatalog = $res[1]
$userId = $res[2]
$password = $res[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I adapted the sequence into the string modifier function and it worked!

Comment: This doesnt work at all if the password has a semicolon in it, like so:
"connectionString=Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=catalog;User ID=userid;Password='pass;word'"

Answer (score 15):

Rather than manually parsing the connection string, you can use [`SqlConnectionStringbuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
$builder = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder -argumentlist "Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=catalog;User ID=userid;Password=password";
$builder["User Id"];
$builder["Data Source"];
$builder["Initial Catalog"];
```

Comment: Sadly `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` doesn't support the Provider property but thanks to your answer I found [`OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN) which does.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace `;` with a newline, you can use [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx) to parse the values into a hashtable:

```
PS> $connectionString = 'Data Source=database;Initial Catalog=catalog;User ID=userid;Password=password'
PS> $connectionValues = $connectionString -replace ';',"`r`n" |ConvertFrom-StringData
PS> $connectionValues

Name                           Value
----                           -----
User ID                        userid
Data Source                    database
Initial Catalog                catalog
Password                       password
```

Comment: Thank you, for your response I will attempt this for the exercise.